# javascript if statement with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Here is my chunk of code:

```
 var update_shipping_methods = function(methods) {
 $(methods).each( function(i) {
 $('div$methods img#shipping_loader').remove();
 var p = document.createElement('p');
 var s = this.name + ' ' + this.rate;
 var i = $(document.createElement('input'))
            .attr('id', this.id)
            .attr('type', 'radio')
            .attr('name', 'checkout[shipment_attributes][shipping_method_id]')
            .val(this.id)
            .click(function() { $('div#methods input').attr('checked', '');                     

$(this).attr('checked', 'checked'); });
if($(methods).length == 1) {
  i.attr('checked', 'checked');
}
var l = $(document.createElement('label'))
            .attr('for', this.id)
            .html(s);
$('div#methods').append($(p).append(i).append(l));
});
 $('div#methods input:first').attr('validate', 'required:true');
return;
```

};

the line:  var s = this.name + ' ' + this.rate; 
is where I need the if statement.  Basically "this" is a shipping name and rate.  I need to write an if statement that basically removes the this.rate if "some rails code"

So if "some rails code";
    var s = this.name;
else
    var s = this.name + ' ' + this.rate; 
end

Does that make sense?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this js code is on a .js file, then I think the best thing is adding an additional parameter to the `update_shipping_methods`:

```
 var update_shipping_methods = function(methods, condition) {
   ...
   var s = condition ? this.name : this.name + ' ' + this.rate;
   ...
 }
```

Then, when you generate the *calls* in your view, you can include the rails condition on the parameter, like this:

```
<script language='text/javascript'>
  update_shipping_methods(methods, <%= your_rails_condition %>);
</script>
```

If adding a parameter is not possible, then the second best solution is adding a global variable called `rails_condition` on the javascript:

```
 var rails_condition = false; // default value
 var update_shipping_methods = function(methods) {
   ...
   var s = rails_condition ? this.name : this.name + ' ' + this.rate;
   ...
 }
```

Then on your view:

```
<script language='text/javascript'>
  rails_condition = <%= your_rails_condition %>;
</script>
```

Regards!

Comment: Ok so I am implementing your second option for now to get something working.  This project is already past budget by to much.

The problem I am having is that it works off of the default and not whats in the rails_condition = <% whatever_method %>;  The way I tested was to simply put true or false in the view and see if that worked and it didn't.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please take his first suggestion. It isn't that much more effort and your code will be cleaner, possibly reusable and you won't be forming the bad habit of using global variables.

Comment: Ok, so I am trying with the first option then, can I do something as simple as: update_shipping_methods(methods, true); 

That's what will be returned by the rails_method.  Basically if a product has a certain Boolean checked then it uses this, if not then it checks out normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put ERb tags in your javascript files, but you could them if the javascript is *in* your ERb template file.  Just put your code in between `<script></script>` and insert `<%= whatever %>` mixed in with the javascript.

Comment: So your basically saying moving that function into the erb file and then I could plug tags in.  The only problem is that, that moves the js into the rails file.  But I guess at some point function has to take precedence over structure

Comment: Yep -- sometimes it's definitely the way to go.